# Im looking for a single line operation to create this matrix:

Tags: matlab

I just started using Matlab, and I am looking for a single line operation, that could create the following vector:
`v1 = [1,3,6,10,15,21]`
As you can see, the point is, that you add **i** to each number, where **i** gets incremented by one everytime, so 0+1=1, 1+2=3, 3+3=6, 6+4=10.
I was thinking of something like
`v1 = v1(1:6) + (1:6)`
but of course that does not return the right values. Could you please help me figure out a way to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something like `cumsum(1:6)`?

Comment: I was looking for this exact function, thank you very much!